# Does WordPress require a full index.php in the root folder? Is there a better way to secure from hacking?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, security

Not a programmer or PHP expert here: please assume entry-level knowledge.

For security reasons, I'd like to allocate the contents of the index.php in my main WordPress folder to something else -- say, `fish.php` and just have an `index.php` that calls it, like so:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php include 'fish.php'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The `fish.php` file would contain everything that's usually in index.php. It would just be named `fish.php`.

Will this completely break WordPress? Is a full, detailed `index.php` file absolutely necessary for it to function, or is it a one-time "load and go" php file that isn't referred to again once WP is in the browser?

Comment: You can't have <?php ?> in a html file. You can set default loading file in a directory using apache (or whatever webserver you run) configuration.

Comment: I'm a numpty. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @dkftw Of course he can if he configured server for that.

Comment: Security through obfuscation never works. Having one file that includes another file carte blanch is not making anything more secure. You want to look at things like file permissions, preventing access to your config files etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing. So you want another file that then includes the contents of `index.php` in WordPress? What are you trying to achieve?  The basic gist of your question seems to be this line:

> Is a full, detailed index.php file absolutely necessary for it to
>   function, or is it a one-time "load and go" php file that isn't
>   referred to again once WP is in the browser?

The way content management systems—or virtually any controller based system—works is to flitter all request in one file & then act on them. In WordPress, that is `index.php`.  And it does more than just load the homepage. It’s the gateway page to all other pages.  So you can muck around with it, but why?  And for what benefit?

**EDIT:** The original poster in the comments to my answer explains that they are thinking of ways to prevent a WordPress site from being hacked. Renaming a file will not work. Especially since `index.php` is only seen on the server side. Let’s say by some crazy config the original poster adjusts Apache to always load `fish.php` as their `index`.  The web browser—and users & bots—will still get WordPress content.  Instead I do the following as a slid brute-force way of avoiding hacks: I place `.htaccess` password protection on the admin areas of CMS systems.  The logic being—and it has worked so far—that most CMS systems are attacked by scripts that hack vulnerabilities  in the admin or login process.  Yes, some bots might get through. But you can eliminate tons of “low hanging fruit” with this method.

For example, below is part of the Apache virtual host config that I will use as an example for a site I am calling `mygreatsite.com` that I have based in the standard `/var/www`. Note that I am adding authorization for `wp-login.php` and `wp-admin` but allowing `admin-ajax.php` to pass since many functions use it.  Now users who administer the site will need to remember an additional—somewhat generic—`htpasswd_wordpress_admin` user/password combination on top of their standard WordPress credentials.  But guess what? Most CMS hacking scripts give up when faced with a browser based password coming from Apache like this.

```
  # Added for WordPress CMS protection.
  <Directory /var/www/mygreatstite.com/wordpress/wp-login.php>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all

    AuthName "WordPress Login"
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd_wordpress_admin

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy Any
  </Directory>

  # Added for WordPress CMS protection.
  <Directory /var/www/mygreatstite.com/wordpress/wp-admin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all

    AuthName "WordPress Admin"
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd_cms_admin

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all

    # Allow 'admin-ajax.php' to pass.
    <Files admin-ajax.php>
      # Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
    </Files>

    Satisfy Any

  </Directory>
```

Comment: Honestly, it's probably not the world's best idea, but since my WP sites get hacked every six months or so, I wanted to try something where I re-name "expected" site files so most scripts built to hack WP automatically won't work on it. So if the script is expecting to find certain things in the index.php file, it... won't. There'll just be this call to another file.

Comment: @mattshepherd It'll not work that way. From the user point of view everything will work just like before. Changes will be visible only via ftp. But if someone got access to your ftp, you just lost everything, so don't bother in hiding files. Keep ftp save and update your WP as soon as new release is available.